# How can I determine what kind of power supply or battery I need for my four NEMA 23 stepper motors?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, stepper-motor, battery-operated

I am trying to determine what current my power supply needs to have for my mini rover project. The NEMA 23 motor specs are as follows: Bipolar amp/phase is 2.8A and the bipolar resistance/phase is 1.13ohms. If I have 4 NEMA stepper motors, does this mean I need a power supply that can supply 2.8*4 = 11.2A of current drawn continuously? I heard on youtube that the 2.8A/phase is the max current, so would I simply round down to 10A of current drawn (or is this untrue)? Would I just purchase two 5Ah batteries and wire them in parallel to achieve 1 hour of operating time?

Comment: a 5 Ah battery is probably rated at 250 mA over a 20 hour time interval ... of you draw 5 A, then it will probably last for 40 minutes, or so .... check the manufacturer's datasheet to be sure

Answer (score 1):

2.8A is the maximum current, but actually nobody uses motors on maximal values. All stepper controllers have the possibility to set up maximum current on each motor depends on your requirements. In most cases, 50% is more than enough. For example, 3D-printers usually working on 1-1.5A current.
Additionally (for 3D-printing) Z-axis moves when other motors in idle state, so even with the maximum current you can save 25% of the expected power.